# When handling browser events in a GWT CellTable, how do I get the most specific within a cell?

Tags: events, gwt, celltable

The onBrowserEvent method of an abstract cell returns a parent element. 
If I have multiple HTML items rendered within the cell, such as spans or divs, how do I get and distinguish which one triggered the event?

Answer (score 2):

[`NativeEvent#getEventTarget()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/NativeEvent.html#getEventTarget%28%29) will give you the exact element that fired the event. You can then walk up until you find an element with some discriminant (e.g. a specific CSS class name), or walk down from the `parent` element and use [`Element#isOrHasChild()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Node.html#isOrHasChild%28com.google.gwt.dom.client.Node%29).

Have a look at how `CompositeCell` [dispatches the event](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/cell/client/CompositeCell.java#133) to the appropriate cell,or how `ButtonCell` checks that you [clicked the button](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/cell/client/ButtonCell.java#56) inside the cell.