# GWT Cell Table Column Sort Handler

Tags: gwt

Im using a GWT Cell Table with sorting enabled on the columns. I am also providing an option of filtering the column. This is roughly how the header looks.

----ColumnName  (Image) -------

When the user clicks on the image, i start off a filtering process. I achieved this using the Cell Table's addCellPreviewHandler. The issue I am facing is , when the image is clicked , the column sorts itself too. Can anyone tell me how to prevent this from happening ? To be clearer, I want the sort to be called when the user clicks anywhere in the header but the image.

Thanks.

```
  breakDownCellTable.addColumn(indexedColumn, columnHeader);
        final int currentColumnIndex = columnIndex;

        // Add a ColumnSortEvent.ListHandler to connect sorting to the
        // java.util.List.
        ListHandler<List<GwtContributorCellData>> columnSortHandler = new ListHandler<List<GwtContributorCellData>>(contributorList);
        columnSortHandler.setComparator(indexedColumn, new Comparator<List<CustomClass>>() {
            public int compare(List<CustomClass> o1, List<CustomClass> o2) {
                if (o1 == o2) {
                    return 0;
                }

                // Compare the columns.
                if (o1 != null) {
                    return (o2 != null) ? o1.get(currentColumnIndex).compareTo(o2.get(currentColumnIndex)) : 1;
                }
                return -1;
            }

        });

        breakDownCellTable.addColumnSortHandler(columnSortHandler);
```

and in the onBrowserEvent method:

```
if("click".equals(event.getType())){
            EventTarget eventTarget = event.getEventTarget();
            if(eventTarget.toString().contains("img") && !eventTarget.toString().contains("<th")){
                //event.stopPropagation();
              //  Window.alert("here");
                //breakDownCellTable.fireEvent()
                ColumnSortEvent.fire(breakDownCellTable, breakDownCellTable.getColumnSortList());
```

Comment: The event object in the event handler may have an `event.stopPropagation()` method to prevent the handlers in the superclass from picking it up. If not, the [CellTable has a default implementation of `ColumnSortEvent.Handler` that you can probably override](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/ColumnSortEvent.Handler.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your can implement a subclass of the cell you're using and override the onBrowserEvent() method.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7641970/1722236) explains how to find out which DOM element is the exact source of the event.

Once you know that the image has been clicked or not, fire the filtering / sorting event accordingly.

Comment: I tried doing this, but Im not quite there yet. I overrode the onBrowserEvent to respond to clicks on the image. Can you clarify a little bit more on how to actually fire the event there? I tried doing the ColumnSortEvent.fire(...) but was not able to disable sorting in the other parts of the image.

Comment: It seems your code has been escaped. Could you post it in your question?

Comment: updated with some code. please let me know if its unclear. Thanks.

Comment: It seems that the FileHandler you are providing will catch the sort event anyway. I would sugget also overriding ListHandler.onColumnSort() and provide your own implementation of ListHandler. I.e do nothing when a ColumnSortEvent is fired, and implement another method that will trigger the sort(super.onColumnSort() will do) that will be called when the image is clicked (which you know already from the overriden onBrowserEvent() method).